# Instalar bibliotecas pelo terminal do linux

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde,
Eu estou a tentar instalar uma biblioteca nova no python 3 pelo terrminal do linux mas não estou a conseguir porque sempre que faço `pip install alguma_coisa` ele instala a biblioteca no python 2.7 e eu pretendia q fosse no python 3 alguem me consegue dar uma ajuda?

P.S: Eu utilizo debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As versões são mesmo separadas e instalar em uma não vai instalar em outra.

Para instalar especificamente para o Python 3 é só usar `pip3 install alguma coisa`

Comment: Eu tentei instalar a biblioteca textract que funcionou perfeitamente no python 2 mas quando tento instala-la no python3 ela da erro e nao instala ela da o seguite erro:`Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx`
Sabe me ajudar??

Comment: Você tem que instalar/atualizar algumas dependências. Aqui está o roteiro https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/209